# Different API response for axios and curl requests

Tags: http, curl, axios

Instagram has an endpoint that gives you a JSON in the response.

When I try to call it using curl I would get a JSON.

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36" https://www.instagram.com/microsoft/\?__a\=1
```

However, if I use other HTTP clients such as Axios for node.js I would get an html page instead. Also for some other HTTP clients I would get 302 redirect occasionally.

```
const axios = require('axios')

axios.request({
  url: 'https://www.instagram.com/microsoft/\?__a',
  headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}
})
```

Is there a way to get around this with axios or other HTTP clients so that they follow the curl behaviour for HTTP requests?

Comment: Will close the question here since Instagram dictates how the API should work and it appears that even if you run two curls you might get 2 different results.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in these cases, is use Postman in order to convert any type of requests, like Curl based request, to any other type, for example axios, fetch etc...